# Dataflow - add JSON file to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm doing some POC with GCP Dataflow and add some JSON object to BigQuery.

```
import apache_beam as beam
import apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery as b_query

p1 = beam.Pipeline()
trips_schema = 'trip_id:INTEGER,vendor_id:INTEGER,trip_distance:FLOAT,fare_amount:STRING,store_and_fwd_flag:STRING'

freq = (
        p1
        | beam.Create(["{\"vendor_id\":33,\"trip_id\": 1000474,\"trip_distance\": 2.3999996185302734,\"fare_amount\": 42.13,\"store_and_fwd_flag\": \"Y\"}"])
        | beam.Map(print)
        | 'Write Record to BigQuery' >> b_query.WriteToBigQuery(table='trips2', dataset='my_poc',
                                                                custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://XXXX-stage'
                                                                                         '-xxxx/temp',
                                                                schema=trips_schema, project='xxxxxxxx-xxx-2',
                                                                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED, )
)
p1.run()
```

Now when I'm running this code, I'm getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: BigQuery job beam_bq_job_LOAD_AUTOMATIC_JOB_NAME_LOAD_STEP_957_6db0f0222c18bf6ef55dfb301cf9b7b2_2e2519daf47e48888bd08fc7661da2e6 failed. Error Result: <ErrorProto
 location: 'gs://xxxx-stage-xxx/temp/bq_load/4b49a738d79b47ba8b188f04d10bf8f0/xxxx-dev-x.my_poc.trips2/258cab64-9d98-4fbc-8c16-087bdd0ea93c'
 message: 'Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. File: gs://xxxx-stage-xxx/temp/bq_load/4b49a738d79b47ba8b188f04d10bf8f0/xxxxx-dev-x.my_poc.trips2/258cab64-9d98-4fbc-8c16-087bdd0ea93c'
 reason: 'invalid'> [while running 'Write Record to BigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/TriggerLoadJobsWithoutTempTables/ParDo(TriggerLoadJobs)']
```

File in the stage bucket which referred in error contains null.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert a `Json` file to a `BigQuery` table with `Beam` and `Dataflow`, you have to read the `Json` file with `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON` format, example :

Your code with a mock as input :

```py
import apache_beam as beam
import apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery as b_query

def map_to_dict(input: str) -> Dict:
    return json.loads(input)

p1 = beam.Pipeline()
trips_schema = 'trip_id:INTEGER,vendor_id:INTEGER,trip_distance:FLOAT,fare_amount:STRING,store_and_fwd_flag:STRING'

inputs: List[str] = [
            "{\"vendor_id\":33,\"trip_id\": 1000474,\"trip_distance\": 2.3999996185302734,""\"fare_amount\": 42.13,\"store_and_fwd_flag\": \"Y\"}",
            "{\"vendor_id\":34,\"trip_id\": 1000475,\"trip_distance\": 2.3999996185302734,""\"fare_amount\": 42.13,\"store_and_fwd_flag\": \"Y\"}"
        ]

freq = (
        p1
        | beam.Create(inputs)
        | beam.Map(print)
        | beam.Map(map_to_dict)
        | 'Write Record to BigQuery' >> b_query.WriteToBigQuery(table='trips2', dataset='my_poc',
                                                                custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://XXXX-stage'
                                                                                         '-xxxx/temp',
                                                                schema=trips_schema, project='xxxxxxxx-xxx-2',
                                                                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED, )
)
p1.run()
```

Example with a `Json` file from `GCS` :

input.json :

```json
{"vendor_id":33,"trip_id": 1000474,"trip_distance": 2.3999996185302734,"fare_amount": 42.13,"store_and_fwd_flag": "Y"}
{"vendor_id":34,"trip_id": 1000475,"trip_distance": 2.3999996185302734,"fare_amount": 42.13,"store_and_fwd_flag": "Y"}
```

```py
import apache_beam as beam
import apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery as b_query

def map_to_dict(input: str) -> Dict:
    return json.loads(input)

p1 = beam.Pipeline()
trips_schema = 'trip_id:INTEGER,vendor_id:INTEGER,trip_distance:FLOAT,fare_amount:STRING,store_and_fwd_flag:STRING'

freq = (
        p1
        | ReadFromText("gs://your-bucket/object/input.json")
        | beam.Map(print)
        | beam.Map(map_to_dict)
        | 'Write Record to BigQuery' >> b_query.WriteToBigQuery(table='trips2', dataset='my_poc',
                                                                custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://XXXX-stage'
                                                                                         '-xxxx/temp',
                                                                schema=trips_schema, project='xxxxxxxx-xxx-2',
                                                                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED, )
)
p1.run()
```

The following conditions need to be respected :

- You need to transform your string to Dict before to save the `PCollection` to `BigQuery`
- The `Json` object should match exactly the schema of the `BigQuery` table. You can ignore extra fields with this parameter in the `WriteToBigQuery` output connector : `ignore_unknown_columns`

Comment: I run your code and the following exception:  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
RuntimeError: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 119 (char 118) [while running 'Map(map_to_dict)']

Comment: Sorry I edited my post with a little correction in tthe input input list. I forgot a comma for the elements in the list. Can you test again please ?

Comment: in a meantime stacked with another problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76436114/dataflow-python-flex-template-fails-with-java-must-be-installed-error :)