# Dataflow python flex template fails with Java must be installed error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm running flex template for PubsubLite to BigQuery Dataflow job.

This is my code:

```
from __future__ import annotations
import argparse
import json
import logging
import apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsublite as psub_lite
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

# Defines the BigQuery schema for the output table.
schema = 'trip_id:INTEGER,vendor_id:INTEGER,trip_distance:FLOAT,fare_amount:STRING,store_and_fwd_flag:STRING'


class ModifyDataForBQ(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, pubsub_message, *args, **kwargs):
        # attributes = dict(pubsub_message.attributes)
        obj = json.loads(pubsub_message.message.data.decode("utf-8"))
        yield obj


def run(
        subscription_id: str,
        dataset: str,
        table: str,
        beam_args: list[str] = None,
) -> None:
    options = PipelineOptions(beam_args, save_main_session=True, streaming=True)

    table = '{}.{}'.format(dataset, table)

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

    pubsub_pipeline = (
            p
            | 'Read from pubsub lite topic' >> psub_lite.ReadFromPubSubLite(subscription_path=subscription_id)
            | 'Print Message' >> beam.ParDo(ModifyDataForBQ())
            | 'Write Record to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table=table, schema=schema,
                                                                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition
                                                                    .WRITE_APPEND,
                                                                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition
                                                                    .CREATE_IF_NEEDED, )
    )

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--subscription_id",
        type=str,
        help="Region of Pub/Sub Lite subscription.",
        default=None
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--dataset",
        type=str,
        help="BigQuery Dataset name.",
        default=None
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--table",
        type=str,
        help="BigQuery destination table name.",
        default=None
    )
    args, beam_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    run(
        subscription_id=args.subscription_id,
        dataset=args.dataset,
        table=args.table,
        beam_args=beam_args,
    )
```

This is my docker file:

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base

ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE="/template/requirements.txt"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="/template/streaming_beam.py"

COPY . /template

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk libffi-dev git \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    # Upgrade pip and install the requirements.
    && pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE \
    # Download the requirements to speed up launching the Dataflow job.
    && pip download --no-cache-dir --dest /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

ENV PIP_NO_DEPS=True

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher"]
```

This is How I'm building template:

```
  gcloud dataflow flex-template build gs://my-bucket-xxxx/templates/streaming-beam-sql.json \
     --image-gcr-path "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/xxxx-xxx-2/dataflow-pubsublite-bigquery/test:latest" \
     --sdk-language "PYTHON" \
     --flex-template-base-image "PYTHON3" \
     --metadata-file "metadata.json" \
     --py-path "." \
     --env "FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE=streaming_beam.py" \
     --env "FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE=requirements.txt" \
     --project "xxxx-xxx-2"
```

Now I'm invoking the template:

```
  gcloud dataflow flex-template run "streaming-beam-sql" \
  --template-file-gcs-location gs://my-bucket-xxxx/templates/streaming-beam-sql.json \
  --project "xxxx-xxx-2" \
  --parameters "subscription_id=projects/xxxx-xxx-/locations/us-central1/subscriptions/data-streaming-xxxx-subscription,dataset=omer_poc,table=trip2"
```

Pipeline launch fails in the logs I see the following:

```
INFO 2023-06-08T22:27:23.260235Z INFO:root:Starting a JAR-based expansion service from JAR /root/.apache_beam/cache/jars/beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform-expansion-service-2.41.0.jar
INFO 2023-06-08T22:27:23.261209Z ERROR:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:Error bringing up service
INFO 2023-06-08T22:27:23.261252Z Traceback (most recent call last):
INFO 2023-06-08T22:27:23.261270Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/subprocess_server.py", line 79, in start
INFO 2023-06-08T22:27:23.261296Z endpoint = self.start_process()
INFO 2023-06-08T22:27:23.261313Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/subprocess_server.py", line 181, in start_process
INFO 2023-06-08T22:27:23.261329Z 'Java must be installed on this system to use this '
INFO 2023-06-08T22:27:23.261343Z RuntimeError: Java must be installed on this system to use this transform/runner.
```

I'm followed google tutorials and workshop materials, but can't find what is the problem. Please help.

**Update**: I already installed jdk 11 as part of my Dockerfile. I also verified that JAVA_HOME is set in the image and java is accessible,

Comment: Upon looking at the error it seems like you need to install JDK on your environment. Please refer to this  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates#set_up_your_development_environment) to download and install the JDK .

Comment: Pub/Sub Lite IO for Python are implemented through x-lang. Check this table: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/connectors/. So Java is needed.

Comment: but the image already has Java11 installed in it look at the Dockerfile RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

Comment: Hi @danny.lesnik,Has your issue been resolved?

Comment: @Unfortunately, it hasn't I moved from PubSub Lite to a Pubsub, to eliminate this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue. The problem is with the way you are building the template using `gcloud dataflow flex-template build`. When you use the `--flex-template-base-image` parameter, your Dockerfile is ignored.

You need to follow the instructions from the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/main/dataflow/flex-templates/streaming_beam):

Build this way. This will use your Dockerfile and push an image to Artifact Registry

```
gcloud builds submit --tag "$TEMPLATE_IMAGE" .
```

Once the image is built, build the flex template:

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template build ${TEMPLATE_GCS_PATH} \
  --image "${TEMPLATE_IMAGE}" \
  --sdk-language "PYTHON" \
  --metadata-file "metadata.json"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can this be correct? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates#python_1